# Filtering Array from contents of another Array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, sorting, filter

I have 2 arrays both with Strings.

```
let exclude = ["text 1", "text 2", "APP", "John"]
let array2 = ["this is text 1", "This is text 2", "This App is under development", "John is working on this project", "This is great"]
```

Im trying to filter any text that is contained in exclude from array2, caseInsensitive.
So in this example it should print `"This is great"`

Instead of using multiple lines for each filter like:
`let filter = array2.filter{!$0.contains("APP")}`

I tried:
`var filter = array2.filter({exclude.contains($0)})`
but it does not filter.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `let filtered = array2.filter { aString in return !exclude.contains(where: { anExcludedString in return aString.range(of: anExcludedString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }) }` with explicit `return` and not `$0` should do the trick.

Comment: The issue with your current logic: You aren't testing case insentive, and you are using `contains` on an array, so you are expecting FULL equality.

Comment: @Larme thank you for clarifying and the fast response. I tried to search the for similar answers but couldn't find anything thus posting. I see the issue now and now I get. Thank you once more.. btw you can post it as answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "explicit" `return` and no `$0`.

```
let filtered = array2.filter { aString in
    return !exclude.contains(where: { anExcludedString in
        return aString.range(of: anExcludedString, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })
}
```

Why `var filter = array2.filter({exclude.contains($0)})` didn't work?

- First issue:
  There is no case insensitive check.
- Second issue:
  You are using `contains()` on a `[String]`, not a `String`. So it expect full equality between the two strings. So if `array2` was `["APP"]`, it would have worked.

For instance if you had:

```
let exclude = ["text 1", "text 2", "APP", "John"]
let array2 = ["this is text 1", "This is text 2", "This App is under development", "John is working on this project", "This is great", "This APP is under development"]
let filtered = array2.filter { aString in
    return !exclude.contains(where: { anExcludedString in
        return aString.contains(anExcludedString)
    })
}
```

Then `"This APP is under development"` would have been removed.

Now, going back to the initial answer, the way to check case insentive is to use `range(of:options:)`.

Comment: Great Answer. Thank you once more

Comment: You can also use [localizedStandardContains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416328-localizedstandardcontains) for a case and diacritic insensitive search